# Grouped overlay bar chart in LaTeX?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have been trying to create a grouped overlay bar chart in latex using pgfplots, much like this one (not actually mine, found randomly on Google):

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is **not** a stacked bar chart, but an overlay bar chart where all bars start at 0, such that taller bars appear "behind" smaller bars.
With pgfplots, it seems quite easy to create bar charts, and to group bars together, but creating grouped overlay bar charts seems to be much more difficult.

Is there a way to create such charts in latex? (not necessarily using pgfplots)

Comment: Can you include a mwe with some data?

Comment: That's very similar to part 3 of [tikz/pgfplot unstacked ybar with “switched” overlay](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126909/tikz-pgfplot-unstacked-ybar-with-switched-overlay). I'm not sure that's a very good idea, because it has the potential to confuse the viewer (how are they supposed to know that the bars aren't stacked?)

Comment: I totally agree with Jake. Your readers would automatically assume that the bars are stacked.