# What is the best way to visualize changes over time?

Tags: graphics, floats, bar-chart

I'm trying to find the best way to create a visual representation of events that occur over time x-axis(?) and change along the y-axis (?). My first attempt was done in Veusz. At the minimum I'd like to find a package that can help me replicate the attached figure. If other, better, options exist, please let me know.

Cheers.

[image: Events and %Change over time]

Comment: With pgfplots you can reproduce this almost trivially *if* you have the data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do have the data but haven't worked with pgfplots before.

Comment: My above comment refers to "At the minimum I'd like to find a package that can help me replicate the attached figure.". I believe pgfplots is such a package. And I had also not used it before I used it for the first time. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - you raise a very valid point! ;-) I have the data for each chart in separate .dat files. Does, pgfplots have a very steep learning curve? Suggestions on a good way to get started?

Comment: It depends on the form your data is in. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126934/194703) for an example that may or may not help, depending on the form of the data. Every learning curve is steep if you learn fast enough.

Comment: Alright. I'm jumping in. My data are in the basic long format. Variable names in row 1. Time (column 1) 1-90, and events are in adjacent columns with values over time (1-90). I suppose the next several hours will be busy. The one example I haven't seen are multi-panel plots. Something else to learn. :-)